# Is Plant Root Growing Box High Pressure Root Grafting Box Growing Breeding Case reliable?

Tags: propagation

This is the first time when I am seeing something like this
It seems simple cheap and ingenious
Does it really work?
https://www.amazon.ca/Reusable-Pressure-Grafting-Breeding-Gardening/dp/B08BNJKR57/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose they're easier to use than trying to wrap a piece of stem in a plastic bag containing some rooting material, which has to be taped in place and is quite fiddly. They're quite inexpensive to buy, but I can't see why the roots will form more quickly than they otherwise would. Rather depends what sort of plant you want to use them for - anything with woody stems that can be air layered would likely be suitable, if it's not possible to simply peg a shoot down into the soil or a small pot and leave it to root itself naturally, but in fact, most plants can be propagated from some type of cutting (soft, semi soft or hard wood cuttings) rather than air layering anyway.

Comment: You can make one of these for free by cutting a slit in an plastic bottle, so it will fit around the stem. Air layering has been used for centuries, but it isn't an "instant" method except on a few types of plants - it may take a year for the roots to develop.

Comment: I need to use it with Roses and maybe a Japanese Maple. Will this method work if we have cold winters? I am thinking that the rooting material bowl might froze and kill the new roots

Comment: If your winters are very cold, then that is a possibility... as for roses, bear in mind most are grafted on other, more vigorous rootstocks, so any you raise in this way, whilst having the correct flowers, may be weaker or have a different growth habit.

Comment: Yeah the rose I have was grafted like this and after killing the spike from the graft support  a coupe of times the graft took over and the plant exploded this year. Since I wanted it in two other spots (want to put it on a pergola to build a privacy screen I thought I could use this method.  I would prefer is since it would allow me to detach and move larger segments of the plan (which went in the wrong direction anyway and I would have to eventually cut them)

Comment: Do I need to water that bag/ball of soil? It i advisable to do it now? We are having a dry and hot month in Toronto
Also there is a question about this: if the branch is too big may be possible that the new root ball is not large enough to support the entire branch ?

Comment: Soil needs to be damp when you first apply it, but I don't see how you can water it ongoing without opening it all up. This type of layering is usually done higher up on a stem, not near the base, so when you sever it, you've not got a very long length of stem above the roots. Should not be done near the base, more likely to get roots off a newer  bit of branch higher  up, though it has to be strong enough to cope with the ball full of  soil being attached.